# ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform

Tags: php, ldap

I'm just starting out with LDAP and Windows Server 2012. I have managed to get my PHP code to bind to the Active Directory using an Administrator account but I can seem to create a new user using the ldap_add function.

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8. I have installed the certificate authority with an enterprise root certificate and I am able to connect to AD using ldp.exe with an SSL connection.

I have looked through Google as well as the 'possible duplicate threads' but none of them have provided me a working answer over the last couple of hours that I have been looking.

When I use the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$ldaprdn  = 'netclass\Administrator'; 
$ldappass = 'password here'; 

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect('ldap://server.netclass.co.uk')
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }


        // prepare data
    $info["givenname"] = "Ronnie Brown";
    $info["samaccountname"] = "br01";
    $info["objectclass"] = "person";

    // add data to directory
    $r = ldap_add($ldapconn, "cn=Ronnie,dc=netclass,dc=co,dc=uk", $info); //Line 28

}
?>
```

I get the output:

```
LDAP bind successful...
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\adduser.php on line 28
```

I have tried to enable SSL by changing:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect('ldap://server.netclass.co.uk')
```

to

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect('ldaps://server.netclass.co.uk')
```

But I then get the following error:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\adduser.php on line 12
LDAP bind failed...
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\adduser.php on line 28
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to work out the answer today.

I added the following line into /etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

After this I was able to connect but was still getting the error message:

```
Server Unwilling to Perform
```

This was because I was trying to set the password plain text like:

```
$ldaprecord["unicodepwd"] = 'MyPassword1234'
```

You need to encode it first so once I change my code to this it works:

```
## Create Unicode password
## Assumes that given password is in UTF-8 encoding!
## Adjust it to the actual encoding of the password
$pwdtxt = "MyPassword1234";
$newPassword = '"' . $pwdtxt . '"';

$newPass = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $newPassword );

$ldaprecord["unicodepwd"] = $newPassw;
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Where i have to find /etc/ldap/ldap.conf.

Comment: Obviusly in /etc/ldap directory, otherwise use shell command "locate ldap.conf" to find right position