# LDAP_add error Server Unwilling

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to add users to windows Active Directory. I'm using xampp. This will be a local page, limited to one two machines only, so I'm not overly concerned with security.  I can get the php script to add users to the Active Directory but only if the UserAccountControl is set to 544. (nomral account and no pw required). If I attempt to add a user with UserControlAccount 512 I get the error: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform. Thru research I know that this is most likely an issue with the password. I've tried several variations on how to set up the password.  Including code from the following posts:

[ldap_mod_replace() [function.ldap-mod-replace]: Modify: Server is unwilling to perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763070/ldap-mod-replace-function-ldap-mod-replace-modify-server-is-unwilling-to-p)

[ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646448/ldap-add-add-server-is-unwilling-to-perform)

[Server is unwilling to perform. LDAP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070725/server-is-unwilling-to-perform-ldap-in-php)

I've checked the Domain Controller and turned off complex passwords, password histories, and other password related policies.  I've made sure that LDAP bind is using ldaps instead of ldap, still no luck. The code is listed below, can anyone see what i'm overlooking here?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$student_ldap = "ldaps://192.168.1.1";
$ldap_port = 636;
$student_ldap_dn = "DC=MyDomain,DC=local";
$student_base_dn = "DC=MyDomain,DC=local";
$student_ldap_usr_dom = "@MyDomain.local";
$student_user = "TestUser";
$student_user_pw = "TestPW";
require_once('connect.php');
$flag = true;
$msg;
$ldapRecord = array();

/* some other unrelated stuff */

if ($flag){
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM cst_CSVexport ';
    $select = odbc_prepare($conn,$qry);
    if (odbc_execute($select,array())){
        if (odbc_num_rows($select)>0){
            while (odbc_fetch_row($select)){
                $first_name = odbc_result($select,'FirstName');
                $last_name = odbc_result($select,'LastName');
                $stuNum = odbc_result($select,'StuNum');
                $ssn = odbc_result($select,'ssn');
                $pw = $first_name[0].$last_name[0].trim($ssn).trim($stuNum).'!';
                /*  
                    begin Password encode attempt from: 
                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763070/ldap-mod-replace-function-ldap-mod-replace-modify-server-is-unwilling-to-p
                */
                $len = strlen($pw);
                $newPW = '"'.$pw.'"';
                $len = strlen($newPW);
                $newPassword = '';
                for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
                    $newPassword .= "{$newPW{$i}}\000";
                }
                $username = $first_name[0].odbc_result($select,'LastName').odbc_result($select,'StuNum');
                echo 'username: '.$username.'<br/>Password: '.$newPassword.'<br/>';
                $ldapRecord['cn'] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
                $ldapRecord['givenName'] = $first_name;
                $ldapRecord['sn'] = $last_name;
                $ldapRecord['sAMAccountName'] = $username;
                $ldapRecord['UserPrincipalName'] = $username.'@MyDomain.local';
                $ldapRecord['displayName'] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
                $ldapRecord['name'] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
                $ldapRecord['description'] = $stuNum;
                $ldapRecord['UserAccountControl'] = "512";
                $ldaprecord['unicodepwd'] = $newPassword;
                $ldapRecord['objectclass'][0] = 'top';
                $ldapRecord['objectclass'][1] = 'person';
                $ldapRecord['objectclass'][2] = 'organizationalPerson';
                $ldapRecord['objectclass'][3] = 'user';
                ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
                if(ldap_connect($student_ldap,$ldap_port)){
                    $brstudent_ldap = ldap_connect($student_ldap,$ldap_port);
                    if(ldap_set_option($brstudent_ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)){
                        if(ldap_set_option($brstudent_ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0)){
                            if(ldap_bind($brstudent_ldap, $student_user . $student_ldap_usr_dom, $student_user_pw)){
                                $dn = 'CN='.$ldapRecord['cn'].',OU=students,DC=MyDomain,DC=local';
                                if (ldap_add($brstudent_ldap,$dn,$ldapRecord)){
                                    echo "User Added: ".$ldapRecord['cn']."<br/><br/>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "User unsuccessful: ".$ldapRecord['cn']."<br/><br/>";
                                    $flag = false;
                                    $msg = 'User not added Sucessfully.';
                                }
                            } else {
                                $flag = false;
                                $msg = 'LDAP bind failed';
                            }
                        } else {
                            $flag = false;
                            $msg = 'set option referrals failed.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $flag = false;
                        $msg = 'set option version failed.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $flag = false;
                    $msg = 'LDAP connect failed.';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $flag = false;
            $msg = 'Select Query returned no results.';
        }
    } else {
        $flag = false;
        $msg = 'Student Query failed.';
    }
}

if ($flag){
    echo '<br/><br/>Accounts created successfully!';
} else {
    echo '<br/><br/>Account creation failed! <br/> Error: '.$msg;
}


?>
```

Comment: I would take the ldap connect/bind logic out of the loop. You only need one connection and then re-use that in the loop. That would also help make the if/else logic easier to follow. Additionally, for AD, do you really have LDAP via SSL setup? Typically you want to use TLS. In that case you keep the ldap port at 389 and issue a `ldap_start_tls($connection)` after the `ldap_connect()`. AD will not set/add a password unless the connection is over an encrypted link. It would probably be easier to use an existing PHP ldap library.

Comment: I've tried ldap_start_tls() with the same result.  It seems to connect successfully using the tls, but still the server is unwilling.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out `$ldapRecord['name'] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;`?

Comment: yes, no change. As it accepts this value if I use UserAccountControl = 544 I wouldn't suspect that as being an issue anyway.  I'm fairly certain the issue is in password.